# "no entry for content://media/external/images/media/0" when using MediaStore.Images and contentResolver to get images stored on device

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I have a very basic requirement. I need the last captured image (and its thumbnail) from the device camera which I can use.

**I use the following code to get the image thumbnail:**

```
String[] projection={MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,
MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA};

Cursor cursor=MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnails(getContentResolver(),MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, projection);
```

**And the following for the actual images:**

```
String[] largeimage_projection={MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,};

String largeFileSort=MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID+" DESC";

Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, largeimage_projection, null, null, sort);
```

However, on running the app on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9, I get the following error:

**For Thumbnails:**

No Entry for content://media/external/images/Thumnails/0

**For images:**

No Entry for content://media/external/images/media/0

Upon checking on the device, I found that the default location for images is "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/"

Also i cannot use the "intent.getExtras()" returned in the onActivityResult() method because i always get this as null for my tab.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks.